# Phing fails inside if statement

Tags: php, build, phing

If i execute this in phing it works well:

```
                <copy todir="${dir.tmp}/${edition}/pdir">
                    <fileset refid="${edition}-p" />
                    <filterchain refid="${edition}-filter" />
                </copy>
```

If i execute it like below (${edition} is set to "c") it fails with following error:

> Execution of target "build" failed for the following reason: [wrapped:
>   You must not specify more than one attribute when using refid]

```
        <if>            
             <or>
                <equals arg1="${edition}" arg2="a" />
                <equals arg1="${edition}" arg2="b" />
                <equals arg1="${edition}" arg2="c" />
            </or>
            <then>                  
                <copy todir="${dir.tmp}/${edition}/pdir">
                    <fileset refid="${edition}-p" />
                    <filterchain refid="${edition}-filter" />
                </copy>                 
            </then>
        </if>
```

Its the same statement like above, only one ref attribute. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in Phing 2.6.0.